# Use of "that" versus "about"

Tags: that

Recently, a student wrote the following sentence:

> Despite Dr.Guitierrez’s assertion that Tina was bit by a lizard, he knew that he was wrong to assure the Bowmans **about** lizards bite children normally.

The correct way to write this sentence could be:

> ...**that** lizards bite children normally"

or

> "...about lizards **biting** children normally".

But I had trouble explaining to the student why their version was incorrect. Can someone help me find an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

**That** is a *conjunction* here, it can attach a *complete sentence* (having a verb in proper tense, etc.) to the previous context.

**About** is a *preposition*. You can only attach a *noun*, a *pronoun* or an expanded *noun phrase* using it. To transform a sentence into a noun phrase you need to replace the verb in its tense with a *gerund*, so that it can be treated like a *noun*. So 'bite' must become 'biting' in this example.